# onClick argument of php function

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I've written the code below to set a variable in `mysql` to either 1 or 0. But somehow whenever i `click` the first button (1) it's always saving the 0-value assigned to the second button in the `mysql` table.

```
<head>
<?php
function update_ziekenwagen($Status) {
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "webapp";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "spoed";
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "UPDATE AlgemeneVars SET value='".$Status."' WHERE id=4";    

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Record updated successfully:" . $Status;
        //echo "UPDATE AlgemeneVars SET value=' " . $Status . " ' WHERE id=4";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();}
?>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Vertr" id="Vertr" name="Vertr" onclick="document.write('<?php update_ziekenwagen(1); ?>');" />
<input type="button" value="Terug" id="Terug" name="Terug" onclick="document.write('<?php update_ziekenwagen(0); ?>');" />
</body>
```

Comment: How have you tried to fix this?

Comment: That's not how it works. You can't call a php (or any other server-side language) function directly from Javascript. Read up on AJAX

Comment: you can do it by using jquery, ajax

Comment: @DigitalDouble is right. What is going on? When you execute the code it will call the `update_ziekenwagen()` function with `1` and then with `0`, so you will always see a `0` value in you database. You don´t need to click the button to save the values. Try this, change the value in your database directly, and the execute the code, do not click the buttons, you will see a `0` saved in the database even without click the button!

Comment: It's a big confusion in your knowledge. The PHP code runs on the server and produces whatever output you want (HTML with inline JS in this case). Both calls to function `update_ziekenwagen()` happens before the generated content reaches the browser. Any user interaction (clicks, f.e.) happens in the browser and do not reach back the server. You can use links, forms or Ajax to send data back to the server.

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<?php
function update_ziekenwagen() {
    $Status = $_POST['status'];
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "webapp";
    $password = "sW7HwM225PxrwbZC";
    $dbname = "spoed";
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "UPDATE AlgemeneVars SET value='".$Status."' WHERE id=4";    

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Record updated successfully:" . $Status;
        //echo "UPDATE AlgemeneVars SET value=' " . $Status . " ' WHERE id=4";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();
}
if (!empty($_POST)){
    update_ziekenwagen();
}
?>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="status" value="1" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="status" value="0" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
```

You can still make it work without using Ajax though using the above code. But this is **NOT** safe or good practice at all.